# How to handle null value in byte[]

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, null, byte

I have binary images in the `Image` column of my database table, but there are some `null` values in the `Image` column. So an exception is thrown at,

> byte[] data = (byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]` because of null.

How to handle this?

Exception message,

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Byte[]'.

My code,

```
using (var sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connstr))
{
    sqlConn.Open();
    ds = new DataSet();

    SqlDataAdapter sqa = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Image from Templates where Shoe='" + selectedShoe + "'", sqlConn);

    sqa.Fill(ds);

    //i got error here
    byte[] data = (byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0];

    .....
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to specifically check for `DBNull` in that column before attempting the cast:

```
byte[] data = null;
if (!ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].IsNull(0))
    data = (byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0];
```

Note that this will fail with the same type of exception if the column in question does in fact *not* contain a byte array.

Comment: Oh i understand your explanation. It works now. Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 2):

Handling nulls at the SQL query worked for me. If your Image column is null, the ISNULL() function will return your next value (0 in this example).

```
SqlDataAdapter sqa = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ISNULL([Image],0) AS Image FROM Templates where Shoe='" + selectedShoe + "'", sqlConn);
```